# Altering return value of method

Tags: java, string, if-statement, return

Lets say that  I have a method that returns a String. I want to check if the returned String is equal to another String and if they are the same to set the returned String to be just "". How would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the "original" string is `str` and the "other" string is `anotherStr`:

```
return str.equals(anotherStr) ? "" : str;
```

Notice that anyway you have to return something if the strings are different, I'm returning `str`, but you'll know what's the appropriate value to return in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare two strings in Java.

```
return str.equals("bla") ? "" : str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up your `check()` method like this, where you pass in the `String` you want to check for, and run it at the end of the method...

```
public String check(String comparison){
    // do some normal processing here, which ends up with a String 'result' that you want to return
    ...

    // Do the check at the end
    if (result.equals(comparison)){
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add the check into the method call itself, which doesn't require you to change the signature of the method...

```
String result = runMethod();
if (result.equals(comparison)){
    result = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the returned string is from another method and i am calling that method and checking if the returned value is equal to the value of a new string that i create.